# Eror list indices must be integers or slices, not str when formattig json

Tags: python, json

I'm getting the following error when running this python script:

```
for departure in snav_live_departures_data ['data']['departures']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is the code

```
ximport urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def cleanText( text ):
    return text.lower().capitalize()

#Snav - live departure
api_url = "https://booking.snav.it/api/v1/dashboard/nextDepartures?callback=jQuery12345&_=12345"
fh = urllib.request.urlopen(api_url)
snav_live_departures_table = fh.read().decode('utf-8')
fh.close()
snav_live_departures_data = json.loads(snav_live_departures_table[16:len(snav_live_departures_table)-2])
print(snav_live_departures_data)
snav_live_departures_data = []
for departure in snav_live_departures_data ['data']['departures']:
    snav_live_departures_data.append({
        "DEPARTURE DATE": departure['departureDate'], 
        "ARRIVAL DATE": departure['arrivalDate'],
        "DEPARTURE PORT": cleanText( departure['departurePort'] ),
        "ARRIVAL PORT": cleanText( departure['arrivalPort'] ),
        "STATUS": "suspended" if departure['is_suspended'] else "active"
    })
with open('snav_live_departures.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(snav_live_departures, outfile)
```

And this is an extract from my JSON data

```
{"success": "OK", "message": "DEPARTURES_FOUND", "data": {"departures": [{"id": 58490, "itinerary_id": 1152, "codcorsa": "CMCA1812280640NG", "ship_description": "Fast Ferry", "delay": null, "is_suspended": null, "notes": null, "type_id": 1, "departurePort": "C/MARE", "arrivalPort": "CAPRI", "departureDate": "2018-12-28 06:40", "arrivalDate": "2018-12-28 07:35"}, {"id": 58471, "itinerary_id": 1148, "codcorsa": "NACA1812280700NS", "ship_description": "Fast Ferry", "delay": null, "is_suspended": null, "notes": null, "type_id": 1, "departurePort": "NAPOLI BEVERELLO", "arrivalPort": "CAPRI", "departureDate": "2018-12-28 07:00", "arrivalDate": "2018-12-28 07:50"},...
```

Comment: I don't think that error comes from that code. It's a nested dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
snav_live_departures_data = []
```

you're overwriting your imported JSON data.

This means when you use

```
snav_live_departures_data['data']['departures']
```

to access the data, you're really trying to access `[]`. Which obviously results in the mentioned error.

Comment: Oh man, how did I miss that?! The question is basically a typo then.

Comment: Thanks, I had that in front of my eyes and missed it.I think it means 'take a break'